# mysql_real_escape on queries

Tags: php, mysql

Should mysql_real_escape to escape the variables  be used for all the queries to the database?

Comment: Nope. mysql_real_escape_string is applicable for the quote-delimited strings only and useless for anything else

Comment: @mario - probably someone looking for a question-voting-related badge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, always escape variables you pass into queries.

Even better, use [PDO](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

This way you don't need to deal with escaping (unless you have queries that require special care).

But if you insist on using the MySQL extension, then use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id;` How does escaping help here?

Comment: @Col.shrapnel I was talking about this kind of query.

Answer (score 2):

Should you always secure query arguments? Yes.
Should you always use `mysql_real_escape_string` for it? No.

If you're not going to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html), consider using [`mysqli_real_escape`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (mind the *i* for *improved*) to encode strings that contain `NUL` (ASCII 0), `\n`, `\r`, `\`, `'`, `"`, and Control-Z. Additional precautions might be necessary though.

[MySQLi](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is the actively developed mysql extension nowadays. The old MySQL extension only gets occasional bugfixes, but is no longer actively developed for quite some time now.

See these two tutorials at DevZone *(but also note that both articles are ancient by internet standards)*

- [ext/mysqli: Part I - Overview and Prepared Statements](http://devzone.zend.com/article/686)
- [Using ext/mysqli: Part II - Extending mysqli](http://devzone.zend.com/article/687)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should escape all variables for security reasons. Escaping numbers, etc. does not change anything, so there is no problem in escaping them, too. You should escape everything, since you might accidentally miss any variable otherwise. I suggest using PHP's [`mysql_real_escape_string()`-function](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or PDO's [prepared statements](http://php.net/pdo).